Why the figure is overflowing out of the text in latex?
I have the below figure in my latex document:

And my latex code is simply:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{timeline2.pdf}}
\caption{Timeline of the methods}
\end{figure}

However the figure does not adjust in the center (even changing the percentage of line width does not affect the centering of whole image). Only the area shown with box would be in the center of the text. I am writing a journal paper where in the template there is also elsarticle. Is there any option for this?

Welcome to TEX.SE ! Please provide a complete small document which reproduce your problem. From your code fragment follows, that your problem should not to happen.

the fbox is wider than linewidth by 2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule but the part sticking out of the box appears to be outside the specified pdf size how did you generate that pdf?

Whenever you are two wide for the page,  the excess pokes into the right margin.  Best you can do is use \makebox[\textwidth]{...} so that it pokes into both margins.

@Zarko @ David Carlisle the point is that the image size is more that 3 MB, and so I couldn't upload it here.  I created the image using OmniGraffle tool.

@JohnKormylo Thanks I tried your solution but didn’t work.

Thanks for your comments. I found a way to solve my issue by aligning the figure to left as below, simple but I didn’t know about that.
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, left]{timeline2.pdf}


Sorry, jour answer is not of any help. The width of image is now only 10% smaler as you get with code in question.  You should be aware that option width=\linewidth limits image size to width of environment, where image is inserted. In your case this is \textwidth, so consequently added frame spill out from image for  \fboxsep+\fboxrule  as mentioned @David Carlisle in his comment. S, question is, how you generate showed image. To see, what is realy going on at you, you should provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) where you simulate real image with some dummy one with the same width.

@Zarko the OP may have difficulty creating a small test image as (unlike EPS) it's really quite hard to generate a PDF with an incorrect media box that is smaller than the actual image.

The picture you present clearly shows that the image file you're trying to include has a wrong bounding box. The frame created by \fbox doesn't cover the part that, indeed, goes beyond the margin.
A PDF file has Media Box and other instructions, such as
MediaBox:            0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
CropBox:             0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
BleedBox:            0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
TrimBox:             0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89
ArtBox:              0.00     0.00   595.28   841.89

Some of these instructions may not be present in your PDF file; they're nevertheless used by pdfTeX for determining the bounding box to assign to the image; the order they are tried is the same as above.
You should regenerate your image or determine, with trial and error, a scaling factor that brings the part outside the bounding box into control.
